# Angular custom theme doesn't change typography

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-material-15

I'm writing a frontend using **Angular 15.2.0** and **Angular Material 15.2.6**.

I want to define a theme that uses these color palettes:

- primary: indigo
- secondary: green
- warn: red

And also use *Noto Sans* instead of *Roboto* as font-family.

I wrote this `theme.scss` file and imported it in my `styles.scss` file:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

// Define custom theme colors
$my-palette-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$my-palette-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette);
$my-palette-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Override default typography
$my-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Noto Sans, sans-serif',
);

// Create custom theme using the defined colors
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-palette-primary,
    accent: $my-palette-accent,
    warn: $my-palette-warn,
  ),
  typography: $my-typography,
));

// Include custom theme in app
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
```

I also changed the font link in `index.html` accordingly:

```html
<link 
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
```

However, as per browser inspector, class `.mat-typography` still comes from `indigo-pink.scss` and sets the CSS rule `font-family: Roboto, sans-serif`. As that font is no longer loaded, it reverts to Arial.

What mistake did I make here?

Comment: Why do you still have indigo-pink.scss in your imports ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, I don't. At least not in my style files, `styles.scss` and `theme.scss`

Comment: check your angular.json !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, bingo, thank you! I guess that's because I started my project with `ng new` and chose a pre-built theme initially. Even so, I thing they should put this choice into `src` files, so that we could alter it later without fiddling with `angular.json`. If you would be interested in make your hint an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an import of `indigo-pink.scss` somewhere. Either in :

- one of your scss files
- your `angular.json` config

Comment: I have the exact same problem. However, when I remove the prebuilt theme from my angular.json file, the browser throws the following error:  "Could not find Angular Material core theme". I've searched for a solution, but all I could find in stackoverflow is: "just add a prebuilt theme to your json, mate!" LOL.

Does anyone know how to solve this elegantly?